# Как PHP называется переменная со скобками $var()?

Tags: php

Только учу php и возник вопрос в разделе анонимные функции и замыкания.

у нас есть конструкция вида

```
$var = function() {
 echo 'hello';
}
```

Если сделать var_dump($var)

```
object(Closure)#1 (0) {
}
```

То все ясно, $var это объект класса Closure, то есть анонимная функция.

Но, как я понял есть еще использование вида $var();

Правильно ли я понимаю, что $var() это функция? То есть, в таком виде, это уже функция, а не объект типа Closure?

var_dump($var()) возвращает null, как для функции у которой нет return.

Что смущает, что то у нас объект, то функция, при добавлении скобок.

Comment: Добавление скобок __вызывает__ функцию, содержащуюся в переменной. `$var()` это значит "вызови фукнцию содержащуюся в `$var`".

Comment: а если эта функция тоже возвращает функцию, то получатся воот такие губищи, $var()()

Comment: @Ипатьев, не могли бы вы привести пример? Пытаюсь изменить свою функцию, чтобы можно было получить какие-то данные через $var()(); но пока только ошибки получаю.

Comment: эээээ. А ЗАЧЕМ?

Comment: Ваш комментарий заинтересовал, т.к. я только учусь и стало интересно, хотел сразу посмотреть.

Comment: Ну так напиши функцию, которая возвращает функцию.

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо, все получилось)